# How to update the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.1.

Comment: When you follow the instructions in the error message, that you quoted in your question, what happens? You should find the plugin in your project's `build.gradle` file, and you should find the `com.google.android.gms` dependencies in your module's `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle`).

Comment: check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker

Comment: Here the link of Google play:: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This error arises when you are using different libraries which have dependencies on different google gems

I was facing the issue with this

This was the code in build.gradle (Module :app )

```
dependencies{
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
}
```

and I resolved this with the following

```
dependencies{
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
}
```

so just a side note , keep your code updated to latest dependencies.

Hope this helps